# Multiple await flow

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await

It is actually related to my previous question and i am quite in capable of unerstanding multiple await .
I understood that one await in async is that  `await` as "pausing" the `async` method until that operation is complete.But I am unable to understand 2 async.

I want to call two api to get data asynchronously and then perform some work based on that.
I have two options and i am not sure what to do.I tried few articles but could not understand as I could not find anything with good diagram explanation.

Can some one please if option 1 is good ?

```
public  void CombineData()
{     
    //**Option1:**
     var MyData = await getCP1();
     var MyData2 = await getCP2();    
     var myobj = MyData.Id+ MyData2.Id;
    //**Option2:**
    var MyData = getCP1();
    var MyData2= getCP2();
    await Task.WhenAll(MyData , MyData2 );
    var myob_2option = MyData.Id+ MyData2.Id;
    }
     public  async Task<MyData> getCp1()
     {
                    var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
                    string requestEndpoint = "localhost/numbers/Get";

                    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _httpRequestPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestEndpoint));

                    IEnumerable<string> numbers = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();
                    return new InsuranceCompanyData();
                }
                public  async Task<MyData> getCP2()
                {
                    var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
                    string requestEndpoint = "localhost/numbers/Get";

                    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _httpRequestPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestEndpoint));

                    IEnumerable<string> numbers = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();
                    return new InsuranceCompanyData();
                }

                private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
                {
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:2351/api/");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    return httpClient;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

Sequence. It does not matter with or without `await`, the code in a method is sequential, ie: first line on the method executes and second one does not until first have ended, and returned control to the calling method. The difference between using it or not is that the thread executing your method will be available while the `awaited` operation is running. This is really usefull if you're dealing with another system, IE: a database. You could await a `SELECT` statement and by doing so you're preventing the thread that executes the method with the select on it to be blocked until the database responds.

Option 2:

Parallelism. Here you sequentially create two tasks and then `await` for the completitude of All of them with `Task.WhenAll()`

So it depends on what you're lookin for, the first option is correct if the second method call needs something from the first one. If there's no dependency between them, what you're looking for is parallelism, which is achieved with option 2.

Comment: and after this if I need to do some work in sequence,I can write that code after Task. WhenAll? .Also,What happens in option one .why await have no use?

Comment: aynchronous programming is for avoiding threads beeing blocked when you're waiting for something "out of your program" (like a query on a DB). If you do this asynchronously the thread instead returns to be available to do other taks while waiting.

Comment: and for the first question, yes. Of course you can treat the returned objects as you would with any other object, there's no difference. But if I'm not mistaken you have to first access the `Result` property of your `Task`s objects after the `WhenAll` call, because this is how you access to the result of them.